# How can i make this image looks well?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <a href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YJZqi7LAW3E/maxresdefault.jpg" target="_blank">
                            <img src="http://blog.kdongwon.com/attach/1/2081007732.jpg" class="img-rounded img img-responsive full-width" alt="Cinque Terre" style="max-height: 141px; max-width: inherit; height: 83px; width: 100%; border-radius: 0;">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-left: 10px;">
                                    <h4><b>Paul</b></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                    <h6>Hello</h6>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want this image looks like square, as you can see on this page : http://jsfiddle.net/rgsgdfsg/1/

But i have a text panel (on snippet, it's like Paul saying hello).

So this panel's height have to be min-height of my image.

I want like this sample : https://www.esafety.gov.au/-/media/cesc/esafety-corporate/games-apps-social-networking/whatsapp/whatsapp-250x440-phone-screenshot-1.png?la=en&hash=26969C8298BD2AC533FE5F7B00AF868FD4B03F1D

Like that sample, i want to display an image on the left of the talk panel. Not being ugly.

**Question :** 
How can i image looks good?

For square and looking good image, i don't care whether some part of image is lost or not.

I want that only width of text panel gets shorter, not image's width or height.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What does "not being ugly" mean?

Comment: You want the image to be same height as text box and also to be square? But what if text box has multiple lines and it's height gets to, say, 200px?

Comment: @Andrija I think, just as a chat bubble of some one's head wouldn't grow if they sent a paragraph of text, he wants the same thing but just a box.

Comment: Then why not just give fixed width and height to img container and set image to width: 100%?

Comment: @Andrija I suppose that text box has only just one line of name and one line of saying. Totally two line. It will be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `<a>` element

```
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Add this to `<img>` element

```
height: 100%;
```

Remove `max-width` and `width` from `<img>`. See also that you have `max-width` on `<img>` two times in style.

Answer (score 1):

Add container with fixed width and height and overflow: hidden.

Insert image in it and center it.

https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/